# Xml Tag not opening when there is no data

Tags: jaxb, resteasy

I am writting a resteasy webservice to produce data in XML format. The XML output works fine when there is data. The real problem comes when there is no data. It stops with parent tag.

if there is no data it looks like this

```
  <salts/>
```

I am looking for this kind of output

```
   <salts>
        <salt/>
   <salts>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing your `salts` collection with an empty collection. Something like this:

```
@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElement(name="salt")
private List<Salt> salts = new ArrayList<Salt>();
```